# How to config Google Datastore index for inequality filter with equity filter

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am working on how to build an index for Google Datastore to do the following query:

SELECT * FROM Place WHERE type = 'something' AND geohashes >= 'XXX' AND geohashes <= 'YYY'

I have created the following index. However, when I do that query, I got an error message: "no matching index found”

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<datastore-indexes
  autoGenerate="true">
    <datastore-index kind="Place" ancestor="false">
        <property name="geohashes" direction="asc" />
        <property name="geohashes" direction="desc" />
        <property name="type" direction="asc" />
    </datastore-index>
   <datastore-index kind="Place" ancestor="false">
        <property name="geohashes" direction="asc" />
        <property name="type" direction="asc"/>
    </datastore-index>
   <datastore-index kind="Place" ancestor="false">
        <property name="geohashes" direction="desc" />
        <property name="type" direction="asc" />
    </datastore-index>
</datastore-indexes>
```

How can build an index in Datastore so that I can do above query? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to run the query in google console?

Comment: Yes. But the result is "You need an index to execute this query."

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried to do query on the property "geohash" with >= , <= at the same time. It works. However, when I add one more property in the query. They show that error message to me.

Comment: @konqi as far as the underlying datastore is concerned you can perform >= and <= comparisons with strings.  You can try it with a single property through the Developers console.  However the minute you combine this with other property equality filters you must have a matching index.  Hence your error.

Comment: Have you turned on automatic index configurations - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig#Java_Using_automatic_index_configuration and tried the query on the dev server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running queries with Datastore, you must provide very specific indexes. This is important because it allows Datastore to guarantee that all queries scale with the size of your result set, **not** your dataset.

In general, I would recommend first running your code using the local development server. This will generate the appropriate indexes for your queries. You can [run the server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver#Running_the_Development_Web_Server) with the command:

```
appengine-java-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.sh <war-location>
```

When you run datastore queries, the file `datastore-indexes-auto.xml` will be generated in your apps directory. This will contain the necessary indexes for any queries that you execute.

For your specific query, your index properties are out of order.

From the [index documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/indexes#Java_Index_definition_and_structure)):

> The rows of an index table are sorted first by ancestor and then by property values, in the order specified in the index definition.

For your specific query, you need the index:

```
<datastore-index kind="Place" ancestor="false">
  <property name="type" direction="asc"/>
  <property name="geohashes" direction="asc" />  
</datastore-index>
```